# ForEach-Object on empty array returns $null

Tags: powershell

Why does the expression `@() | ForEach-Object { $_ }` evaluate to `$null`? I would expect it to return an empty array.

Is there a short expression to coalesce $null to an empty array for PowerShell 5? In PowerShell 7 I can do `$array ?? @()`.

Comment: Simply wrap your pipeline in another array-subexpression: `$alwaysArray = @(@() | ForEach-Object { $_ })`

Comment: Consider what your example does; it passes nothing to the pipeline. Foreach-Object has no objects to iterate over.

Comment: Thanks for answering the second question. But still I am wondering why PowerShell behaves the way it does. In every other language I know, mapping an empty list still results in an empty list.

Comment: Or use the [unary comma operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.1#comma-operator-) to wrap the emty array in a new single-element array. Upon return, PowerShell will unwrap the surrounding array leaving you with the inner (empty) array. `$a = ,(@() | ForEach-Object { $_ })`. You can also do that on $null: `$a = ,$null; $a.GetType()` --> `Object[]`

Comment: Check this: `@() |ForEach-Object { $_ } |ForEach-Object { 'Test' }`. In other words, it doesn't return a `$Null`, it returns a [`System.Management.Automation.Internal.AutomationNull`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.internal.automationnull) which it changed in a `$Null` when it is assigned to a variable. See: [**Everything you wanted to know about $null**](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-null).

Answer (score 2):

try wrap your command with an array operator `@`.

so it will be -

```
$array = @(@() | ForEach-Object { $_ })
```

Comment: This only works because `ForEach-Object` returns a void object. If it would actually return `$null`, `$array` would have 1 element. Is there a similar construct that also works for `$null`?

Comment: I downvoted this answer because it doesn't answer the question "*Why does the expression @() | ForEach-Object { $_ } evaluate to $null?*". In fact, it returns an [**Emprty Null**](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-null), a [`System.Management.Automation.Internal.AutomationNull`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.internal.automationnull) which will changed in a `$Null` only *when it is assigned*. Check this: `@() |ForEach-Object { $_ } |ForEach-Object { 'Test' }`.